# How to use type for event in xml?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, cache, full-page-cache

I want to call my observer after the `adminhtml_cache_refresh_type` event and specifically after `full_page`

This method does not work, is there a way to do this in observer?

```
<event name="adminhtml_cache_refresh_type" type="full_page">
```

Answer (score 1):

yes theres a way to do this in observer:

make a file called events.xml in etc folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="adminhtml_cache_refresh_type">
        <observer name="RefreshCacheType" instance="Mageplaza\yourmodule\Observer\RefreshCacheType" />
    </event>
</config>
```

in your observer file RefreshCacheType.php:

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\yourmodule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Version;
use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool;
protected $cacheTypeList;
protected $cacheFrontendPool;

class RefreshCacheType implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $orderFactory;

    public function __construct(
        TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList, 
        Pool $cacheFrontendPool
    ){
        $this->cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
        $this->cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        
$_types = [
            'config',
            'layout',
            'block_html',
            'collections',
            'reflection',
            'db_ddl',
            'eav',
            'config_integration',
            'config_integration_api',
            'full_page',
            'translate',
            'config_webservice'
            ];
 
    foreach ($_types as $type) {
        $this->cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
    }
    foreach ($this->cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
        $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
    }



    }
}
```

Comment: This decision does not mean what I mean.

Comment: you cannot use <event name="adminhtml_cache_refresh_type" type="full_page"> like this especially the type= "full_page", you can make an observer on the adminhtml_cache_refresh_type event and can do what you need in the observer.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `type="full_page"` is wrong attribute.**You can not use like this.**